# Comment dire « (email) mailing list » en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

Mon employeur a une « mailing list » d'email (de courriel pour les Québécois) pour discuter des questions de la langue et la culture française. Parfois, il y a des questions à propos de la « mailing list » elle-même, et je voudrais y répondre en français. J'ai recherché sur Google, mais les réponses ne sont pas satisfaisantes. Alors :

*Comment dis-je « mailing list » en français ?*

---

My employer has an email mailing list to talk about questions on the French language and culture. Often, there are questions about the list itself, and I'd like to be able to answer them in French. I searched on Google, but the answers weren't good enough. So:

*How do I say "mailing list" in French?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wikipédia redirige [mailing-list](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailing_list) vers **liste de diffusion** ou **liste de distribution**. L'article met en garde contre la confusion possible avec **liste de discussion**, mais personnellement je ne vois pas vraiment la différence. Les deux premiers termes feront cependant plutôt référence à une diffusion à sens unique, alors que le troisième indique que tous les abonnés à la liste peuvent y envoyer des messages.

J'ai parfois aussi lu le terme **liste de publipostage**, nettement moins joli et à utiliser dans le contexte de l'envoi de messages publicitaires.

---

Wikipedia redirects [mailing-list](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailing_list) to **liste de diffusion** or **liste de distribution**. The article warns against the possible confusion with **liste de discussion**, but I personally don't see much difference, except that the first two might mean a more one-way communication, while the third might be more suitable when all subscribers can post messages to the list.

I've seen the expression **liste de publipostage** used sometimes, but it doesn't look as good as the other ones, and refers to advertisement mailing.

Comment: Je n'emploierais jamais *liste de publipostage* car *publipostage* renvoie, que je sache, à de la ***publicité***. ("Publipostage" est le terme pour l'envoi de publicité par courrier.)

Comment: @Circeus Effectivement. J'ai mis ma réponse à jour afin d'apporter cette précision.

Comment: "Liste de discussion", c'est plutôt Usenet et les serveurs NNTP (ou du moins, c'est le terme couramment utilisé par les mauvaises traductions des logiciel de courriels). Ce n'est pas la même chose.

Comment: "Liste de diffusion" et "liste de distribution" sont différents dans le contexte de certains logiciels de courriels comme Outlook : le premier terme fait référence à un ensemble d'adresses collectées par l'utilisateur (le courriel est alors envoyé par l'utilisateur à toutes ces adresses), tandis que le deuxième fait référence à une adresse courriel à laquelle on peut écrire pour envoyer à un ensemble d'autres adresses (c'est alors le serveur de courriel qui redirige, ces dernières adresses étant "membres" de la liste, comme dans une "liste de discussion" mais à sens unique).

Answer (score 14):

Le terme couramment utilisé est *liste de diffusion*.

---

The commonly used term is *liste de diffusion*.

Answer (score 0):

Les Canadiens étant de longue date confrontés au problème de la traduction des anglicismes, leur [Bureau de la traduction](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bureau_de_la_traduction) a construit un site pour ce genre de questions: Termium, [qui opte pour la traduction *liste d'adresses*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=mailing%20list).

La *Commission d'enrichissement de la langue française* a quant à elle produit un clone de Termium: [FranceTerme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme). Le fruit du travail de cette commission nous indique qu'une *mailing list* [est soit un *fichier d'adresses*, soit une *liste de diffusion*](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=mailing-list).

Le terme [publipostage](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=publipostage&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) quant à lui est la traduction de [mailing](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=mailing).